# Topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I dont get a passage in a demonstration of this Theorem
$f: X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ if continuous if, and only if $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$ for all $F \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ closed.

I now that this is true for open set so exist a prove using complementary sets.

$\Rightarrow$ Let $F \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be closed then $\mathbb{R}^{m} - F$ is open so $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{m} - F)$ is open in $X$ if $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{m} - F) = X - f^{-1}(F)$ the result follow, but this equality.

I could prove that $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{m} - F) \subset X - f^{-1}(F)$ but the reverse doesn't make sense to me. Why $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{m} - F) \cup f^{-1}(F) = X$ assuming that $f$ is continuous in $X$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inverse mappings preserve unions. That is, $$f^{-1}[S] \cup f^{-1}[T] = f^{-1}[S \cup T]$$ for any mapping $f$. In your case, $$ f^{-1}[\mathbb{R}^{m} - F] \cup f^{-1}[F]= f^{-1}[\mathbb{R}^m] = X$$ since $\mathbb{R}^m$ covers the range of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of $f$ is $X$, and the range of $f$ is $R^m$. So $$p\in f^{-1}(R^m-F)\iff (p\in X\land f(p)\in R^m-F)\iff$$ $$\iff(p\in X\land f(p)\not \in F)\iff (p\in X\land p\not \in f^{-1}F)\iff$$ $$\iff p\in X-f^{-1}F.$$

Comment: Notice that your  theorem applies to any   function $f:X\to Y$ for any spaces $X, Y. $  Another property that is equivalent to continuity is that whenever $S\subset X$  and $p\in Cl_X(S)$ we have $f(p)\in Cl_Y(f(S)).$